# css resizing div container to fit small windows

Tags: css, resize, height, carousel

My problem is that the container will not resize to fit smaller screens or when the window size shrinks. I have tried the percentage method, where I set height/width to 100% or even 50%, the container disappears. After spending weeks on this, I have got absolutely no where. 
There is a requirement to support IE6 as well, which drives my head in.

```
.ca-container{
 position:relative;
 margin:-45px auto 20px auto;
 width:990px;
 height:500px; 
}

.ca-wrapper{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:relative; 
}

.ca-more{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 10px;
 right:0px;
 padding:4px 15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 background: #000;
 text-align:center;
 color: white;
 font-family: "Georgia","Times New Roman",serif;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #897c63;    
}

.ca-item{
position:relative;
float:left;
width:330px;    
height:100%;
text-align:center; 
}

.ca-item-main{

 padding:20px;
 position:absolute;
 top:5px;
 left:5px;
 right:5px;
 bottom:5px;
 background:#fff;
 overflow:hidden;
 -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Here is the html for my webpage. I have truncated it just to show the structure of the first item (I have removed my content)

```
        <div class="container">                
            <div></div>
            <div id="ca-container" class="ca-container">
                <div class="ca-wrapper">
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3></h3>
                            <h4></h4>
                            <a href="#" class="ca-more">Read...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                <h6></h6>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>xxxxxxxx </p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The original plugin is the circular content carousel: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/16/circular-content-carousel/

I have realised the original plugin does not do that. If my code is too messy, please check out the plugin and solve the issue with the demo source.

Any help will be greatly appreciated - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at media queries? http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

you can have different css for different size screens - here is a lot of info on the internets at the moment about them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have fiddled with @media screens and noticed the size changing and moving around, so thats progress - however I just cant get it to stabilise, the containers go all over the place. Also, I will need this to work in IE6 as well.

Do you mind trying it with the original plugin? Thanks soo much